# Where a profile has become unclickable, what happened to the account?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, deleted-accounts

I [helped a user here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499859/javascript-for-3-dynamic-drop-down/16500404) a few weeks ago, but their profile is now unclickable (I presume it was not like this at the time, as I would have noticed).

I've not seen this before - what does it mean? Did the user request the deletion of their profile, or was it deleted by a moderator? Why would someone ask a question, and then disable any way to interact with respondents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does it mean?

That looks like a deleted account.

> Did the user request the deletion of their profile, or was it deleted by a moderator?

Most probably by request, but since we anonymize deleted posts, it is not possible to tell for certain.

It is also possible that the user deleted the account themselves (which they can do if they don't have any upvoted content, for instance).

There is another possible explanation - the question poster could have asked for the question to be disassociated from their account.

> Why would someone ask a question, and then disable any way to interact with respondents?

Dunno. You would have to ask them. Rage quitting does happen.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks Oded. Just curious as to the spontaneous disappearance; the question I answered is the only one in the Google cache. Might be worth deleting the question anyway - it's probably too localised.

Comment: Don't you have access to the deleted account to see who deleted it and why?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - The association is gone. That's the point of deletion, after all. It _could_ be that the question OP requested that the question be disassociated with their account, but those are rare and few between.

Comment: Sure, but as a dev I expect some way to see those things to correct mistakes or just be able to keep track.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I may be able to hunt this down on the DB level, but frankly - too much work.

Comment: Fair enough, just expected there is some kind of log (not public of course, even not for mods) of deleted accounts.